# Can a Rails `where` query with question marks be done more elegantly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say you have a simple query in Rails which goes like this

```
a = 42
Klass.where("`column_1` = ? OR `column_2` = ? OR `column_3` = ?", a, a, a)
```

Can this be done more elegantly so that you don't need to type `a, a, a` three times? It works fine but it looks horrible.

Comment: i guess if you have different column and different argument in where clause you need to pass 3 variable.

Answer (score 11):

Can try something like this

```
Klass.where(["`column` = :a OR `column` = :a OR `column` = :a", { a: user_name }])
```

Comment: Curly braces is not necessary here.

Comment: `Klass.where("column = :search OR column = :search OR column = :search",  search: user_name )`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I will use a find by with a in condition such as:

```
 Klass.find_all_by_column([1, 2, 3])
```

Replace 'column' with column name you wish to search in.
Replace 1,2,3 by your value, it's an array you can add or remove values from it.

My example will generate a SQL query such as:
    SELECT * FROM Klass WHERE Klass.column IN (1,2,3)

More on this on [Active record documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Klass.find_all_by_column([1, 2, 3])`?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this more elegantly.

I'm guessing your columns should all be different columns, right? Please be more specific in your question.

You can only simplify the statement if the columns are the same and the values are different.

```
abc = [42,21,84]
Klass.where("column IN (?)", abc)
```

Comment: or even more succinctly, `Klass.where(:column => abc)`

Comment: Yeah they're different columns (OEPS!)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your line

```
Klass.where("`column` = ? OR `column` = ? OR `column` = ?", a, a, a)
```

can be changed into

```
Klass.where(["`column` = ? OR `column` = ? OR `column` = ?"] + a*3)
```

Comment: @sevenseacat I tried, I use it and it works in Rails 2 applications with the `:conditions` option in `find` function, and have never done Rails 3 queries :)

Comment: this does not work because `a*3` just add more elements to the first array